# outputting data as dictionaries in a new python file

Tags: python, dictionary

I like to store my data after a longish python program as dictionaries in a new script. This then allows me to import the program (and hence data) easily for further manipulation.

I write something like this (an old example):

```
file = open(p['results']+'asa_contacts.py','w')
print>>file, \
'''
\'''
This file stores the contact residues according to changes in ASA
as a dictionary
\''' 
d = {}
'''
```

followed by a lot of faffing around entering the dictionary code as a string:

```
print>>file, 'd[\'%s\'] = {}'               %st
```

I was wondering if there was a module which did this automatically as it would save me a lot of time.

Thank you

Edit: it may be useful to know that these dictionaries are usually several layers deep like this one I'm using today:

```
d[ratio][bound][charge] = a_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but try the inbuilt function repr.

```
repr(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a specific reason that you need source code -- and I suspect there isn't, you just want to serialize and deserialize data from disk -- a better option would be Python's [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. There are times when changing the source code after it has been written is important (like this one unfortunately), but there have been several times where the increased speed of cPickle would have been excellent

Answer (score 0):

[Lossy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975808/outputting-data-as-dictionaries-in-a-new-python-file/6975843#6975843) of `repr` happens to work, but `repr` isn't *specifically* designed for serialization. I think it would be slightly more robust to use a tool designed for that purpose; and since you want something that's human-readable and -editable, `json` is the obvious choice.

```
>>> import json
>>> animals = {'a':'aardwolf', 'b':'beluga', 'c':'civet', 'd':'dik-dik', 
               'e':'echidna', 'f':'fennec', 'g':'goa', 'h':'hyrax', 
               'i':'impala', 'j':'javelina', 'k':'kudu', 'l':'lemur', 
               'm':'macaque', 'n':'nutria', 'o':'orca', 'p':'peccary', 
               'q':'quagga', 'r':'reebok', 's':'serval', 't':'tenrec', 
               'u':'urial', 'v':'vole', 'w':'wallaroo', 'x':'xenurine', 
               'y':'yapok', 'z':'zoologist'}
>>> s = json.dumps(animals)
>>> s[:60] + '...'
'{"a": "aardwolf", "c": "civet", "b": "beluga", "e": "echidna...'
>>> animals = json.loads(s)
>>> animals['w']
u'wallaroo'
```